# Unable to load an installed package in R

Tags: r, installation, r-package

While trying to install and load the package Hmisc in RStudio, I ran into an error. Upon inspection, it turned out to originate from ggplot2. I can replicate the error on my machine as follows:

```
> install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies=TRUE)
# see bottom of this post for the full log of this command.
> library(ggplot2)
Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called 'ggplot2'
```

I have reinstalled RStudio and its packages, but without success. Also, some other packages (such as AER) do work properly.

**Any advice on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.**

---

---

Full log of `install.packages("ggplot2")`:

```
Installing package into <some library>
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘rlang’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘scales’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
cli        3.2.0  3.4.1              TRUE
rlang      1.0.2  1.0.6              TRUE
lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.3             FALSE
scales     1.2.0  1.2.1             FALSE
ggplot2    3.3.5  3.3.6             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/cli_3.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1255499 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rlang_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1718546 bytes (1.6 MB)
downloaded 1.6 MB

package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    <some library>
installing the source packages ‘lifecycle’, ‘scales’, ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 106854 bytes (104 KB)
downloaded 104 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/scales_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 270609 bytes (264 KB)
downloaded 264 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.3.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3061989 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing <some library>
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'scales'
* removing <some library>
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'scales' is not available for package 'ggplot2'
* removing <some library>
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    <some library>
```

After being advised to install rlang, I first ran `remove.packages(rlang)`, and then `install.packages("rlang")`, type="source"). However, when I then run library(rlang), I get the error `Error in library(rlang) : there is no package called ‘rlang’`. Here is the output of `install.packages("rlang")`:

```
Installing package into < some library >
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rlang_1.0.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 742508 bytes (725 KB)
downloaded 725 KB

* installing *source* package 'rlang' ...
** package 'rlang' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rlang'
* removing < some library >
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    < some library >
```

Comment: Check for error messages during installation.

Comment: @jay.sf, thank you. I have just edited my post to include the log of the installation command.

Comment: You need to install the latest version of rlang. (You have version 1.0.2 but you need 1.0.6). Clear your workspace, restart R, then `install.packages("rlang")`. Then try again.

Comment: @jay.sf, unfortunately, this did not work. I did exactly what you said but I get the exact same error message. Also, when I run `library(rlang)`, I get the warning: `package ‘rlang’ was built under R version 4.0.5`

Comment: @Value_Investor Did you really mean me? I don't use `rlang` at all.

Comment: @Allan Cameron, unfortunately, this did not work. I did exactly what you said but I get the exact same error message. Also, when I run `library(rlang)`, I get the warning: `package ‘rlang’ was built under R version 4.0.5`

Comment: @jay.sf, sorry, wrong person.

Comment: @Value_Investor you can't have got the exact same error message. Part of the error message in your question says `namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required`. Can you perhaps update your question to show the actual current error output?

Comment: @AllanCameron, yes, I have just pasted the current output of `install.packages("ggplot2")`, after having run `install.packages("rlang")`. It seems that R chooses to install the binary version (whatever that may be), which is version 1.0.2., while the source is 1.0.6. However, I do not know how to adjust this.

Comment: Try `install.packages('rlang', type = 'source')`

Comment: @AllanCameron, thank you for the suggestion, but now I even get an error when I run `library(rlang)`. I've included the output in the post.

Comment: The new error means that you need to first install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).

Comment: @AllanCameron, after consulting my professor, I reinstalled R itself and it now works fine. Thanks tremendously for your help nonetheless.